# How to modify opcache.interned_strings_buffer from .htaccess with php_value

Tags: apache, .htaccess, opcache, php

I'd like to modify `opcache.interned_strings_buffer` to 12 via `.htaccess` file

I've added the following block to `.htaccess`:

```
php_value opcache.interned_strings_buffer 12
php_value max_execution_time 180
php_value max_input_vars 1760
```

However only `max_execution_time` and `max_input_vars` changed.

I verified that values changed by inspecting `phpinfo()` output.

How to change `opcache.interned_strings_buffer` via `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to documentation, most opcache directives are PHP_INI_SYSTEM so they should be changeable on httpd.conf or .htaccess. But opcache is a zend extension and value cannot be updated via .htaccess. I guess this is the problem.

There is [a ticket on php.net](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71042) opened for 4 years.

Comment: is there any way to do this custom change on website level without modifying apache `php.in`?

Comment: No, there isn't, but.. No, I never found a solution to update config. But, you can disable the cache by using something like `php_flag opcache off`.

Comment: somehow, on shared hosting accounts i see that `public_html` folder has custom `php.ini` which overrides `opcache.interned_strings_buffer` and it overrides `php.ini` of apache. though can't get it work on local station.

Comment: @rok there are fundamental differences regarding this, depending on how PHP is integrated with Apache to begin with. Configuration via .htaccess is possible when the Apache module version of PHP is used, custom php.ini files apply only when PHP is embedded using FastCGI or similar.